# NUTCH does not crawl a particular website

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I'm using Apache NUTCH version 2.2.1 to crawl some websites. Everything works fine except one website which is the http://eur-lex.europa.eu/homepage.html  website.

I tried with the Apache NUTCH version 1.8, I have the same behaviour, nothing is fetched.
It fetches and parses the entry page but after that it is as if it can not extract its links.

I see always the following:

```
------------------------------
-finishing thread FetcherThread5, activeThreads=4
-finishing thread FetcherThread4, activeThreads=3
-finishing thread FetcherThread3, activeThreads=2
-finishing thread FetcherThread2, activeThreads=1
0/1 spinwaiting/active, 0 pages, 0 errors, 0.0 0 pages/s, 0 0 kb/s, 0 URLs in 1 queues
-finishing thread FetcherThread0, activeThreads=0

-----------------
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the site's robots.txt file restricts your crawler's access to the site.

By default nutch checks the robots.txt file, which is located in http://yourhostname.com/robots.txt, and if it's not allowed to crawl that site it will not fetch any page.